.NET Maui CarouselView Problems newbie
I am sorry if this question is a bit newbie. But I have spend like 10 hours trying to understand how to do what I want.
I have tried a lot of things with CurrentItem, CurrentPosition, and a lot more. But nothing of it seems to work.
I basically want a TotalPrice property in my view model to update, to the corresponding value from the currently focused carouselView item.
Here is my code. I really hope someone can help me :-)
XAML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="CarouselVIewDemo.MVVM.Views.StartPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    Title="StartPage">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <CarouselView
            x:Name="CarouselTest"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Margin="4"
            CurrentItemChangedCommand="{Binding CarouselViewItemChanged}"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            IndicatorView="indicatorView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding CarouselViewItems}"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid RowDefinitions="*,*">
                        <Frame
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            BackgroundColor="Beige"
                            BorderColor="DarkOrange"
                            CornerRadius="50"
                            HasShadow="True"
                            HeightRequest="110"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            WidthRequest="140">
                            <Label
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                FontSize="Large"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                Text="{Binding ProductName}"
                                VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        </Frame>
                        <Label
                            x:Name="{Binding ProductPrice}"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Padding="0"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="Large"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            Text="{Binding ProductPrice, StringFormat='{0:kr #,##0.00}'}"
                            VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>

        <IndicatorView
            x:Name="indicatorView"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Margin="2"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            IndicatorColor="Black"
            IndicatorSize="8"
            IsVisible="True"
            SelectedIndicatorColor="DarkOrange"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />

        <Label
            Grid.Row="2"
            FontSize="Large"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="{Binding TotalPrice}" />

    </Grid>
</ContentPage>

<!--
    NOT USED ATM
    Position="{Binding ProductPrice}"
-->
<!--  CurrentItem="{Binding}"  -->

View model:
using CarouselVIewDemo.MVVM.Models;
using PropertyChanged;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace CarouselVIewDemo.MVVM.ViewModels
{
    [AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
    public class StartPageViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Product> CarouselViewItems { get; set; } = new();

        public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; } = new();

        public ICommand CarouselViewItemChanged =>
            new Command(() =>
            {               
                // This will always show the value of index 1 -
                // Instead I want it to show the price of the Product that -
                // Is currently selected in the XAML CarouselView.
                TotalPrice = CarouselViewItems[1].ProductPrice;                                          
            });

        public StartPageViewModel()
        {                       
            CarouselViewItems = new ObservableCollection<Product>
            {
                new Product
                {
                    ProductId = 1,
                    ProductName = "KaffeBønner",
                    ProductPrice = 35m
                },
                new Product
                {
                    ProductId = 2,
                    ProductName = "LakridsKonfekt",
                    ProductPrice = 55m
                },
                new Product
                {
                    ProductId = 3,
                    ProductName = "Shampoo",
                    ProductPrice = 25m
                },
            };            
        }
    }
}


This always shows the value of index 1 because you are doing CarouselViewItems[1].ProductPrice;
Bind to the CurrentItem property of CarouselView which can be ProductCurrentItem = CarouselViewItems[0] by default using ObservableProperty and then using the  ProductCurrentItem To get the TotalPrice in your CarouselViewItemChanged or using CurrentItemChanged event
Instead of creating a new variable for that just bind to the ProductCurrentItem.TotalPrice in your view for the label. So unless you are doing anything extra in your command, you can safely remove that
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace MauiApp1;

public class ProductModel {
    public int ProductId {get; set;}

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
}

public partial class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    [ObservableProperty]
    ProductModel _productCurrentItem;

    public ObservableCollection<ProductModel> CarouselViewItems { get; set; } = new();

    [ObservableProperty]
    decimal _totalPrice;

    public ICommand CarouselViewItemChanged =>
        new Command(() =>
        {
            TotalPrice = ProductCurrentItem.ProductPrice;
        });

    public ViewModel()
    {
        CarouselViewItems = new ObservableCollection<ProductModel>
        {
            new ProductModel
            {
                ProductId = 1,
                ProductName = "KaffeBønner",
                ProductPrice = 35m
            },
            new ProductModel
            {
                ProductId = 2,
                ProductName = "LakridsKonfekt",
                ProductPrice = 55m
            },
            new ProductModel
            {
                ProductId = 3,
                ProductName = "Shampoo",
                ProductPrice = 25m
            },
        };

        ProductCurrentItem = CarouselViewItems[0];
    }

}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage"
         >

   <Grid BackgroundColor="White" RowDefinitions="300,Auto,Auto,Auto">
        
        <CarouselView
            x:Name="CarouselTest"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Margin="4"
            CurrentItemChangedCommand="{Binding CarouselViewItemChanged}"
            CurrentItem="{Binding ProductCurrentItem}"
            IndicatorView="indicatorView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding CarouselViewItems}">

            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto">
                        <Frame
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            BackgroundColor="Red"
                            BorderColor="DarkOrange"
                            CornerRadius="50"
                            HasShadow="True"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            WidthRequest="140">
                            <Label
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                FontSize="Large"
                                TextColor="Black"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                Text="{Binding ProductName}"
                                VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        </Frame>
                        <Label
                            x:Name="{Binding ProductPrice}"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Padding="0"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="Large"
                            TextColor="Black"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            Text="{Binding ProductPrice, StringFormat='{0:kr #,##0.00}'}"
                            VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>

        <IndicatorView
            x:Name="indicatorView"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Margin="2"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            IndicatorColor="Black"
            IndicatorSize="8"
            IsVisible="True"
            SelectedIndicatorColor="DarkOrange"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />

        <Label
            Grid.Row="2"
            FontSize="Large"
            TextColor="Red"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="{Binding ProductCurrentItem.ProductPrice}" />

        <Label
            Grid.Row="3"
            FontSize="Large"
            TextColor="Red"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="{Binding TotalPrice}" />

    </Grid>

</ContentPage>



Side note: Frame is deprecated, use Border instead.

Hi thanks for trying to help me. I am afraid I don't understand your answer. I know the value is always showing index 1. since I hardcoded that. The problem is I dont know understand how to make it show the currentItem price dynamically. I would like to use a command since I have this problem in a bigger project. I was just trying to isolate the problem here to make it more easy to explain. I get this error if I try to do as you suggested. I get a exception unhandled. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Can't set CarouselView to position -1. ItemsSource has 3 items.'

I have just updated the answer with sample use. I have added the label using ProductCurrentItem and also kept using TotalPrice as a seperate property @MichaelChristensen

Hello again. Thanks a lot for taking time to help me out. I managed to get it to work :-)

You can try to use CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentItem}" for your CarouselView to achieve this.
You can define a variable CurrentItem in your view model and bind it to property CurrentItem of your CarouselView.
 public Product CurrentItem { get; set; }`

Please refer to the following code:
StartPageViewModel.cs
public class StartPageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Product> CarouselViewItems { get; set; }

    public Product CurrentItem { get; set; }


    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; } = new();

    public ICommand CarouselViewItemChanged =>
        new Command(() =>
        {
            // This will always show the value of index 1 -
            // Instead I want it to show the price of the Product that -
            // Is currently selected in the XAML CarouselView.
            //TotalPrice = CarouselViewItems[1].ProductPrice;
        });

    public StartPageViewModel()
    {
        CarouselViewItems = new ObservableCollection<Product>
        {
            new Product
            {
                ProductId = 1,
                ProductName = "KaffeBønner",
                ProductPrice = 35m
            },
            new Product
            {
                ProductId = 2,
                ProductName = "LakridsKonfekt",
                ProductPrice = 55m
            },
            new Product
            {
                ProductId = 3,
                ProductName = "Shampoo",
                ProductPrice = 25m
            },
        };

        CurrentItem = CarouselViewItems[0];
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");

    }


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}

Usage example:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:MauiCarouselViewApp422.ViewModels"
             x:Class="MauiCarouselViewApp422.MainPage">


    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vms:StartPageViewModel></vms:StartPageViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <CarouselView
            x:Name="carouselView"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Margin="4"
            CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentItem}"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            IndicatorView="indicatorView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding CarouselViewItems}"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid RowDefinitions="*,*">
                        <Frame
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            BackgroundColor="Beige"
                            BorderColor="DarkOrange"
                            CornerRadius="50"
                            HasShadow="True"
                            HeightRequest="110"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            WidthRequest="140">
                            <Label
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                FontSize="Large"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                Text="{Binding ProductName}"
                                VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        </Frame>
                        <Label
                            x:Name="{Binding ProductPrice}"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Padding="0"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="Large"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            Text="{Binding ProductPrice, StringFormat='{0:kr #,##0.00}'}"
                            VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>

        <IndicatorView
            x:Name="indicatorView"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Margin="2"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            IndicatorColor="Black"
            IndicatorSize="8"
            IsVisible="True"
            SelectedIndicatorColor="DarkOrange"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />

        <Label
            Grid.Row="2"
            FontSize="Large"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference carouselView}, Path=CurrentItem.ProductPrice,StringFormat= '{0:kr #,##0.00}'}" />

    </Grid>
</ContentPage>

Note:
Here, we can bind the defined variable CurrentItemto Label(carouselView is the x:Name of the CarouselView ).
           <Label
            Grid.Row="2"
            FontSize="Large"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference carouselView}, Path=CurrentItem.ProductPrice,StringFormat= '{0:kr #,##0.00}'}" />


Hello. Thanks a lot for taking time to help me.

Also another question. Regarding your solution. When doing it with MVVM architecture, I don't think I should use the bindings like the way you are doing it x:Name="carouselView"  ?

This is determined on a case-by-case basis. If we define CurrentItem like this: public Product CurrentItem { get; set; }, we need to do this. If we add ObservableProperty tag for CurrentItem (e.g. [ObservableProperty]
Product currentItem; ), we can bind like this:  <Label  Text="{Binding   CurrentItem.ProductPrice,StringFormat= '{0:kr #,##0.00}'}" />.

And you can also implement INotifyPropertyChanged for your ViewModel and add OnPropertyChanged for CurrentItem, in this case, you don't need to do this either(Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference carouselView}, Path=CurrentItem.ProductPrice,StringFormat= '{0:kr #,##0.00}'}") .
